# How to string with list in c#.net?

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains file name. I want to check whether it is valid or not. I don't know how to compare a single string with list.

Ex.

```
string fileName = "my\file.jpg";  //it is invalid file name as it contain \
List<string> invalidCharacter = new List<string>();
invalidCharacter.Add("\");
invalidCharacter.Add("<");
invalidCharacter.Add(">");
invalidCharacter.Add("?");
```

I want to check whether `fileName` contains any character of `invalidCharacter` list.
I have thousands of such name. So, I can not use loop of list for compare every string.

Can anybody please suggest better way to compare string with list?

Comment: have you tried `regx`?

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes. I think it helps to perform faster than this.